# How is it possible for a String literal to use methods and properties of String Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, object, methods, javascript-objects

```
var str1 = "Sagar"; //String literal
var str2 = new String("Sagar"); //String Object
str1.length; // Output: 5
str2.length; // Output: 5
```

/* How is it possible for a string literal like in str1 variable to access the properties and methods? */

Comment: Because a string literal is an object of type String.  What did you think they were?

Comment: Okay. I know that the string literal is an object of type String. But how javascript knows the difference between the string literal and string object.

Comment: Please check the duplicates mentioned at the top.

Comment: There ISN"T a difference.  A string does not exist as a string.  Javascript simply does not have that concept.  A string literal implicitly creates an object of type String.